# Style in Graphics or Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics, style

To generate a yellow sphere, I usually write the code without using `Style`:

```
Graphics3D[{Yellow, Sphere[]}]
```

However, `Style` seems to be a more rigorous form in many references:

```
Graphics3D[Style[Sphere[], Yellow]]
```

I really seldom use `Style` even in more complex and lengthy code project. Should I or not?

Please, your suggestions and comments.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I think that in cases like this it does not make a difference.

Comment: I'm with Szabolcs on this. In cases like your example, it doesn't make any visible difference. General principle: if there no visible difference or measurable penalty, go with the simpler code.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you for editing my first post in Mathematica.SE. I also follow the rule of simplicity in general. In that reason, I seldom use Style even in more complex and lengthy code project. But, I wanted to know if I am missing something: the hidden power of Style.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `Graphics` and `Graphics3D` `Style` behaves mostly as a grouping construct like [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html).  You can use `List` (instead) for most things, even Options like [`FontSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontSize.html) or [`Antialiasing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Antialiasing.html)

```
Graphics3D[{FontSize -> 40, Text["sample"]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1], {Antialiasing -> False, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.8]}}]
```

[image]

There are however directives that only work in `Style`, e.g. styles defined in the style sheets:

```
Graphics3D[Style[Text["sample"], "Title"]]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[Style[Text["sample"], "TI", 40]]
```

[image]

This is *not* valid input:

```
Graphics3D[{"TI", 40, Text["sample"]}]   (* bad input *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to know that kind of differences. Good to know that anything defined in a Stylesheet should be included in Style instead of List.